# How an alphabet file is processed in NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I trained a model using the commands found here...

https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell#train

There is no problem with the English text. But I need to train a similar model based on Hindi Corpus.
I have a file that can be replaced with `sherlockholmes.txt` but I am not sure what should I refer to instead of `alphabet_en.txt`.

Should I just collect all Unicode characters used in Hindi in a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, following the example for English you are supposed to collect all of the characters that are used in the Hindi text of the corpus (here stored in `sherlockholmes.txt` file).

I guess these characters help the algorithm figure out which characters compose words and which characters are not (e.g. punctuation).